# what is major difference between selenium1 and selenium2

Tags: selenium-webdriver

what is major difference between selenium1 and selenium2

Comment: Isnt it mentioned on their site?

Comment: @d-live The problem is that Selenium 2 makes it sound like Selenium 2 is "Selenium 1 + a bit more". However, they are two related but different bits of software, and that's not explained very well on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium 1 = Selenium Remote Control.
Selenium 2 = Selenium Webdriver, which combines elements of Selenium 1 and Webdriver.

The big downside of Selenium RC was that it was written in JavaScript, so depended on the browser's JavaScript engine as to how it would run. This made tests buggy.

Selenium 2 integrated Google's Webdriver project. It's an interface that runs the JavaScript natively, so you only need to write the test once and Selenium will test on different browsers.

Therefore, Selenium 1 works with just about every browser - if it has a JavaScript engine, it will probably work. However, Selenium 2 needs a driver for that browser. Although there are drivers for all the biggest browsers, for testing the maximum range of browser / OS combinations, it is better to use Selenium 1. If you are just testing the most common browsers, Selenium 2 is more accurate.

Comment: This is only partially correct.  See [my answer to "What is the difference between Selenium IDE, Server, RC, 2.0, and WebDriver?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996322/241753) for the full answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of members in the "Selenium" family. Those generally called "selenium 1" and "selenium 2" are Selenium RC and Selenium Server, respectively.

Both are server programs meant to remote control a browser so you can call it from elsewhere. They work the same way, the main difference in "selenium 2" is the integration of the WebDriver API.

More details here : http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Also, please do some research. Google already knew the answer to this question. :)

Comment: I would +1, but for the unnecessary 'please do some research' comment.

Comment: @Blowski I did not mean to be rude - but if we want sites like this one to continue being useful, it's important to avoid asking questions that can easily be answered with the information already avaliable. 
Also that question wasn't too good : very generic, one line long, with an expeditive phrasing.

Sorry if I offended you - I would probably have not written that comment if the original asker took a bit more time writing his question.

Comment: It makes StackOverflow sound like a less friendly place. Answer the question (as you did), provide links (as you did), and use flags or downvotes as necessary.

Comment: @Blowski Sry, I'm a bit new. Noted, will do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information from the WebDriver page and their FAQ at  [http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_So,_is_it_like_?*Or*?](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_So,_is_it_like_?_Or_?)