# What is the difference between Selenium IDE, Server, RC, 2.0, and WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Selenium seems to have a lot of different components and the website does not explain them very well and I'm still a bit confused which is which. What's the difference or purpose between:

Selenium IDE
Selenium Server
Selenium Remote Control
WebDriver
Selenium 2

My understanding is as follows:

**Selenium IDE** is a GUI plugin used for rapid prototyping of test cases in Selenese/HTML.

**Selenium Server** is a standalone java program which allows you to run HTML test suites in a range of different browsers, plus extra options like reporting.

**Selenium Remote Control** is the old name for Selenium Server, which only supports version 1 of the Selenium API.

**WebDriver** is the actual core API which has bindings in a range of languages and allows you to write standalone tests.

**Selenium 2** is the latest version of the Selenium project, and includes the IDE, Server and WebDriver.

Comment: Well, you've pretty much got it covered in your question :) Which parts are you confused about or need clarification?

Comment: Good to hear, I was just looking to see if I'd go anything wrong. Well, I'm a bit confused about the relationship between the Selenese test cases and a full blown script in WebDriver. Is the Selenese a kind of IDE-only "binding" that references parts of the full WebDriver API?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're almost right.

- Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin used for rapid prototyping of test cases in Selenese/HTML, which can also export test cases in a variety of programming languages.
- Selenium Server is a standalone java program which allows you to run test cases written in a variety of programming languages with a variety of web browsers, and which can additionally run HTML test suites in a range of different browsers, plus extra options like reporting.  (My point is that the --htmlsuite option of selenium-server.jar is not its primary function, and will soon be split out into a separate program.)
- Selenium Remote Control is an API for programming tests in a variety of languages in Selenium 1 and Selenium 2, and also the name of the Selenium 1 server that runs the API.
- WebDriver is an API for programming tests in a variety of languages in Selenium 2, which can run with or without a server.
- Selenium 2 is the latest version of the Selenium project, and includes the IDE, Server and both the Selenium RC and WebDriver APIs.

In addition:

- Selenium Grid is a server that distributes tests across a set of Selenium Servers.  In Selenium 1 it is a separate server, in Selenium 2 it is integrated into the Selenium Server.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in saying that SRC is supported in Selenium 2 for legacy purposes, but Webdriver is the future for the API?

Comment: The Selenium RC API is not being enhanced, and indeed there have been only a handful of bugfixes in the last year or two, and the WebDriver API is the Selenium Project's primary focus.  But the **VAST** majority of Selenium users use IDE, which shares the core JavaScript implementation with RC.  The WebDriver users are still a very small proportion of the Selenium community.

Comment: @Ross Patterson - "WebDriver is an API for programming tests in a variety of languages in Selenium 2, which can run with or without a server." - why do you want to run a WebDriver with the server?

Comment: @Pangea: I didn't say it's a good idea, in fact I think it's a bad one.  But the Selenium developers deliberately constructed it that way, and before they introduced the RemoteWebDriver driver, WebDriver didn't have a server-based execution mode.

Comment: @Pangea: You need the server component if you want to run the test and the browser on two separate machines.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is good, but since then better explanation were posted on internet:

- [Relationships between different versions of Selenium](http://yizeng.me/2014/04/25/relationships-between-different-versions-of-selenium/) - with a graph of relations
- [Architecture of Selenium WebDriver](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html) by Simon Stewart, explaining history of the project, and challenges. Fascinating reading!