# How to integrate different test automation in web project

Tags: testing, web, automation, phantomjs, robotframework

I want to test all the feature in my web site just like regression test, which is used to guarantee new code do not make other feature crash.

The test i need is just like this:

1. Login the website with a normal user account to check if the login works well.
2. Signup a new normal user to see if the signup feature works well.
3. Login and go to some page to see there is no error or warning showing on the page.
4. Login the website with an admin account to see if all the admin page works well.

Here is some tools I have found something like what i need.

1. phantomjs casperjs: headless webkit which can do website navigation and run javascript
2. robot framework   : it looks like a frameworks for test but i have no idear right now.
3. selenium          : I have tried the firefox plugin, it is nice.

And i have seen that some people recommand the vs2010 for test but my team dont use vs...we use emacs, vim so i dont think it is a good choice.

Most importantly, how can i integration these test frameworks with the unittest in my projects? I have no idea on how to choose one to make them together.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

RobotFramework is more of a scripting framework, if I can call it that. It provides a runner/executer which will use an existing automation Library (or yours) which runs through your test. Works with Selenium.

Selenium also allows for headless browser testing:

- [Does Selenium support headless browser testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing)
- [Running Selenium Headless](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/)
- [Running Selenium Headless with Jenkins CI](http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/setting-up-selenium-server-on-a-headless-jenkins-ci-build-machine.html)
- [Other google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+headless)

You can also use Jenkins/Hudson or [similar Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Continuous_Integration_Software) software to run different 'batches' of tests - unit, system, integration, regression, etc.